# How to retrieve number with prep_match_all()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Inside my webpage "http://www.my_web_page" I have something like that:  img border="0" class="borderx" id="pic_15132"

I wanna know which parameter did I have to use inside preg_match_all("") to retrieve only the number.
Here is what I tried but my result is:  _15132

```
$webpage = file_get_contents("http://www.my_web_page");

   preg_match_all("#_([^>]*)[0-9]{6}#", $webpage , $matches)
        foreach($matches[0] as $value) 
            { 
                echo $value . "<br>"; 
            }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$webpage = file_get_contents("http://www.my_web_page");

preg_match_all("#_[^>]*([0-9]{6})#", $webpage , $matches)
   foreach($matches[1] as $value) 
      { 
          echo $value . "<br>"; 
      }
```